# Mudar background a partir do horario (Problema)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso mudar o background a partir de um certo horário, porém o site já estava meio feito então o carregamento do background está sendo feito no jquery com essa função

```
    $(".intro").backstretch("img/" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    images.length)] ,   { centeredX:true, centeredY:true});
```

ai basicamente tentei fazer isso

```
   $(window).on('load', function () {

    var today = new Date()
    var curHr = today.getHours()

    /*HORARIO Menor que 12 horas*/ 
    if (curHr < 12) {
    var images = ['london.png'];

$(".intro").backstretch("img/" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
images.length)] ,   { centeredX:true, centeredY:true});  
}
else{
var images = ['outra imagem'];

$(".intro").backstretch("img/" + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
images.length)] ,    { centeredX:true, centeredY:true});  
}
 }
```

Alguém sabe porque não funciona? ah e se precisarem da classe .intro está aqui

```
 .intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  height: 100%;
  background: #000 url(../img/5.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
```

Se alguém souber o porque não funciona agradeço, obs: se for para fazer por css
chamando uma classe e passando o horario chamar outra eu consigo, mas quero desse modo, porquê já está estilizado, obs não entra dentro dessa função.

Comment: Remove o background do css..

Comment: removi, mas nada...

Comment: Creio que seria somente uma imagem por período certo? Se sim não precisa do random, é só definir data imagem por período ( em alguma var ) e usar a função já criada:

$(".intro").backstretch("img/"+imagem_selecionada,  { centeredX:true, centeredY:true});

Answer (score 0):

Consegui galera, foi erro meu desculpe, ja tinha um load la em cima então acho que estava em conflito, perdão mesmo obrigado